# SVR Model -->Feature Scaling - Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand what is wrong with the code below. I know that the `Y` variable is `1D` array and expected to be `2D` array and need to reshape the structure but that code was working previously fine with a warning.

```
# Importing the libraries
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
  dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
  X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
  y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values



# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

---

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got a 1D array instead:
array=[  45000.   50000.   60000.   80000.  110000.  150000.  200000.  300000.
  500000. 1000000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is in the error message:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has
a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Since you're passing in a single feature (not a single sample), try:

```
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: Can you also help me which tutorial is best to start with basic and advanced python?

Comment: @Ramangoyal, for basic Python, I'm a big fan of http://automatetheboringstuff.com! For more advanced Python for data analysis, I highly recommend Wes McKinney's Python For Data Analysis, notebooks here: https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why a 2D array is required ? after all, the data is simply "normalized", one do not need a 2D array.