# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. How to reslove this?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

There is an Error which throws an Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. THw error is detailed below, also find the complete code after the Output,

**Output:**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-d2ec9bb14152>", line 5, in <module>
    y = sc_y.fit_transform(y).reshape(1,-1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 553, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 639, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 663, in partial_fit
    force_all_finite='allow-nan')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 521, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  45000.   50000.   60000.   80000.  110000.  150000.  200000.  300000.
  500000. 1000000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample*```



The complete code is as follows:

**Code:**

```# SVR Template
# Data Preprocessing

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values # 1:2 is to consider X as a matrix
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values


# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)


# Fitting the SVR Model to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X,y)

# Predicting a new result 
y_pred = regressor.predict([[6.5]]) 

# Visualising the SVR Results
plt.scatter(X,y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR Model)')
plt.xlabel(' Position Level ')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show() ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksQs2.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to: [stackoverflow question from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426857/svr-model-feature-scaling-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead)
The error message is saying exactly what you need to do:
`y = sc_y.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1))`
However, I don't think you need to standard scale your ys to achieve good performance with SVR (the x yes though) [ref of statexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re).

Comment: Thanks! @Yacine that worked, However I got another, `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 10]`

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: `File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 205, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 10]`

Comment: I'm guessing lengths are the shape of your sample row in your feature matrix. I would suggest to print their shape to check what is happening with them. It's either some features which are of different length or you did some reshaping somewhere which you shouldn't have done with your setup.

Comment: This is the Output: ` print(y.shape)
(10, 1)`

Comment: So your y shape is messed up then. Don't scale your ys, you don't need it for a Support Vector Regression. If you  remove `y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)` everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Yacine, tried restarting the kernel. And it worked.

Comment: Great @AbhishekNair don't forget to accept my answer