# sklearn - knn Value Error: Expected 2d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am currently learning about knn and tried to do some forecast,

 but it ended up with the following error: "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead".

 Although I looked up some threads, I don't know how to reshape the array.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics

data = pd.read_csv('justAnUrl')
X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data.iloc[:,13].values
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.25, random_state=100)

sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# a)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn_list = []

for x in range(25):
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
    matches = 0
    if y_pred[x] == y_test[x]:
        matches = matches + 1
    precision = matches / len(y_pred)
    knn_list.append(precision)

print(knn_list)
```

[table's header](https://gyazo.com/3be16d8605b91e64f8536ad60bb7f012)

The data is about heart diseases.

Hope you can help me and others can learn from this example as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508553/expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead-how-to-reslove-this check if it helps you

Comment: @DouglasFerreira If I do so, I just get told, that X has just 1 feature but the StandardScaler is expecting 13.

Comment: does adding ```values```  to the end of ```data.iloc[:,:-1]``` change anything?

Comment: Then maybe you want .reshape(1,-1) instead of .reshape(-1,1)

Comment: If I add values it does change nothing. If I swap the reshape values it says X has 227 features but the StandardScaler is expecting 13 features as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your train_test_split order is wrong, it should be
`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split()`

eidt: i.e. you're fitting scaler on X_train and also trying to transform y_train using that scaler. Sort out the order and it should be fine.

Comment: I tried this train_test_split, but it does not change the result. I still get the 2d array error